# Which is the relation between objects in a category $C$ and its collection $ob(C)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, foundations

Given a category $C$, we say that objects are in $ob(C)$ which is presented as a class; so it looks obvious that, if $a$ is an object of the category $C$, the relation between $a$ and $ob(C)$ is (a sort of) membership. Nevertheless, in some sources it seems accepted that categorical foundational enterprises are conceptually autonomous from elementhood.

For example in https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/category-theory/#PhilSign we can read this passage: "It has been recognized that it is possible to present a foundational framework in the language of category theory, be it in the form of the Elementary Theory of the Category of Sets, ETCS, or a category of categories, of Makkai Structuralist foundations for abstract mathematics, SFAM. Thus, it seems that the community no longer question the logical and the conceptual autonomy of these approaches, to use the terminology introduced by Linnebo & Pettigrew 2011".

How's it possible to think about categorical framework to be autonomous from a theory of elementhood (such as a set/class theory in whichever form) if categories are dependent from (a sort of) membership relation? I specify that I'm not talking about a particular class theory or an already existing one; I'm just saying that, so to say, membership comes first if you are working in a categorical framework. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not qualified to answer this deep question, but to quote a few sources that are too long to fit in a comment.

In [a recent post on FOM](https://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2022-May/023284.html), Harvey Friedman wrote,

> Mac Lane realized that any attempt to remove set theory from the
> picture, and have notions like category as primitive, is likely doomed
> not only in terms of its complexity, but also in terms of its
> Philosophical Coherence. So Mac Lane didn't even attempt to do such a thing, at least in this book.

Even in [the exposition of ETCS](https://topologicalmusings.wordpress.com/2008/09/01/zfc-and-etcs-elementary-theory-of-the-category-of-sets/), it was written that

> A lot of confusion seems to reign around “the categorical approach to
> foundations” and what it might entail; some seem to think it involves
> a “doing-away with elements” that we all know and love, or doing away
> with sets and supplanting them with categories, or something like
> that. That’s an unfortunate misunderstanding.

I guess the above objections are rather philosophical. According to [the nLab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fully+formal+ETCS),

> This page addresses a frequently voiced but easily corrected
> misconception about categorial approaches to foundations of
> mathematics, namely that there is a logical circularity in using
> category theory to give an axiomatic set theory (such as ETCS), since
> categories themselves are sets (or collections) with extra structure.
>
> The most straightforward response is a formalist one: category theory
> and various elaborations like ETCS are first-order theories, just as
> ZFC is. One doesn’t need a theory of sets prior to a theory of
> categories, any more than one needs a theory of sets prior to a theory
> of sets...

Comment: "One doesn’t need a theory of sets prior to a theory of categories, any more than one needs a theory of sets prior to a theory of sets", that's wrong. A first-order theory of sets like ZFC needs a metatheory upon which its models (and often even its syntax) are based. The point, illustrated by Friedman citing MacLane in the first quotation, is that membership relation (i.e. classes) are at the core of categories, so even if you have a categorial metatheory for category theory, you have elementhood at the base.

Comment: @UmbertoCavasinni You certainly don't need a set theoretic meta theory to *use* ZFC (or a first-order theory of categories). You need set theory in the background to talk about *models* of ZFC, sure. But all you need in the meta theory to prove theorems is the ability to do very basic constructions with strings of symbols from a finite alphabet! This is the point of the quotation.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't say that you need a *set-theoretic* metatheory to use ZFC or a first-order theory of categories (same for models because it depends on your definition of them). Ok, if the point is that, it isn't wrong as I wrote. The problem, however, isn't that you need sets in the metatheory, but that you need a membership relation because categories are defined upon it, hence categorial foundation (legitimate as it can be) isn't autonomous from it. In your example: suppose you define alphabet as a collection of symbols; can you say that your foundations are independent from elementhood?

Comment: @Umberto_Cavasinni Mentally you can't avoid elementhood and that might be the strongest philosophical standing, but this is not necessarily the case in terms of first order logic. E.g. PA doesn't support the idea of subsets of natural numbers, even natural numbers as a whole is a fabrication beyond PA itself. Even for interpreting ZFC in a model, $\in$ is not necessarily the membership relation.

Comment: Exactly, like I said before about models. I can add that there isn't (necessarily) a thing as *the* membership relation. Nobody's saying that PA is a possible foundation of all mathematics and one that is independent from elementhood. The problem is always there: *a* membership relation has to be specified prior to categories, so every tentative foundation over category theory is dependent from such a relation. Maybe the answer is that this precise relation can be viewed in terms of categories, but that's circular, isnt't it?

Comment: It's not circular when you don't include membership in your definition of categories, which is possible through a first order formalization. I don't undderstand why you keep saying membership has to be specified prior to categories.

Comment: Because: suppose that we want to pursue a foundational enterprise based upon categories but independent from elementhood. How can we answer the principal question? We have to know which is the relation between objects and $ob(C)$ and it must be different from classical membership, otherwise we have to drop the independence claim (as MacLane did, Friedman says in the above quotation).

Comment: $ob(C)$ isn't (necessarily) part of the first order formulation. Like the relationship between $0$ and $\mathbb N$ is a meaningless question in PA. There is no $\mathbb N$ in PA.

Comment: Of course, in the theory; my question regards a formalism-free context because we're talking about "conceptual autonomy" of a categorial foundation. As I said before, a first-order theory doesn't solve the problem here: for a first-order theory we have to sepcify the semantcs and the problem is again there (if we want to maintain the conceptual autonomy). The question isn't about circularity; the perspective which seems problematic is the claim of conceptual independence (formalism-free) from elementhood of a categorial foundation.

Comment: We don't need to specify semantics for a first order theory.

Comment: A first-order theory is a class of sentences closed under semantical consequence. But, aside from this remark, my question is about a problem which can arise only if you want to prove a claim (conceptual autonomy of a categorial foundation), not in general; if you don't assume this pov, you can't answer the question (because, obviously, in that case you haven't any problem). "Consider categories as models of a theory" doesn't prove the claim because categories rely upon the relation between objects and $ob(C)$ and this would be the autonomous concept of the tentative foundation.